# How to debug bzImage's decompress?

Tags: linux-kernel, debugging, gdb

I already know that vmlinux is needed when debugging the kernel through gdb.

But I need to debug the decompress and EFI entrypoint of bzImage.

In this case, how can I debug bzImage with gdb?

Currently, even when bzImage is loaded, there are no symbols, making debugging difficult.